# mgcv on Databricks: the value of k-index not identical to that from RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, azure-databricks, gam, mgcv

I've developed a GAM model for some beta-distributed variable in RStudio with the mgcv package and am now transferring the code (one-to-one) in an R-Notebook on Azure Databricks.

One of the many things one should check while working with such models is whether the dimension of the basis of smooth functions is appropriate. This is done in the mgcv-function `k.check` which computes the so-called k-index.

My problem: In both environments, I use the same dataset and the same model parameters while fitting my model. But the k-index which gets computed in Databricks is different from the one computed in RStudio!

The call:

```
 k.check(modell_mo, subsample = length(data_mo_train[,1])+ 1)
```

produces in RStudio the output:

```
                       k'      edf   k-index p-value
  s(Intervall_Nummer) 20 19.76659 0.9149797       0
```

and in Databricks:

```
                      k'      edf   k-index p-value
  s(Intervall_Nummer) 20 19.76659 0.9636656       0
```

Note that I set the subsample parameter to the size of the dataset in order to avoid the random sub-setting which is otherwise used while computing the k-index. In particular, if I repeat the computations, I always get the same k-index in each of the environments.

For the moment, I'm fine with not-so-brilliant values of edf and p-values. I tried to copy the code from Databricks back to RStudio, but with no effect. The discrepancy is still there.

Comment: Are R and mgcv versions identical?

Comment: I would check that the model fits are exactly equivalent; `k-index` is based on the model estimated scale parameter, which may be getting estimated slightly differently in the two fits.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: Thanks.  When I use the same versions of R and mgcv in both environments, I get the same fit (+ characteristics like r squared etc become also identical), but the discrepancy in k-index is still there.

Comment: @Roland: The R and mgcv versions were not identical, and neither were the coefficients of the model. However, using the same versions does not fix the problem.

Comment: Are both systems 64bit? (I maintain a CRAN package that uses numeric optimization and I was never able to exactly reproduce results in my unit tests on all systems CRAN uses for checks.)

Comment: @Roland: Yes, both 64bit. (You mean there's nothing to worry about?)

Comment: Have you followed Gavin's advice and compared the scale estimates? Have you compared predictions from these two model fits?